# Start Service When STREAM_VOICE_CALLS Is In Focus

Tags: android, audio, service, stream, call

I'm working on an Android application.

I have a service (Float Service). This service is a circular button. I want that this service start only when `STREAM_VOICE_CALLS` selected. I mean that for example in VOIP calls or in phone calls and this service stops only when `STREAM_VOICE_CALLS` unselected.